# Haskell: catching low level IO exceptions

Tags: haskell, exception, io

According to [the System.Directory haddock](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.6.2/html/libraries/directory-1.2.0.1/System-Directory.html#v:renameFile), `renameFile` may fail with a number of reasons:

- HardwareFault A physical I/O error has occurred. [EIO]
- InvalidArgument Either operand is not a valid file name. [ENAMETOOLONG, ELOOP]
- isDoesNotExistError / NoSuchThing The original file does not exist, or there is no path to the target. [ENOENT, ENOTDIR]
- isPermissionError / PermissionDenied The process has insufficient privileges to perform the operation. [EROFS, EACCES, EPERM]
- ResourceExhausted Insufficient resources are available to perform the operation. [EDQUOT, ENOSPC, ENOMEM, EMLINK]
- UnsatisfiedConstraints Implementation-dependent constraints are not satisfied. [EBUSY]
- UnsupportedOperation The implementation does not support renaming in this situation. [EXDEV]
- InappropriateType Either path refers to an existing directory. [ENOTDIR, EISDIR, EINVAL, EEXIST, ENOTEMPTY]

A couple of these (isPermissionError, isDoesNotExistError) have testing functions, but others (including UnsupportedOperation, in which I'm interested) don't seem to correspond to anything. What is `UnsupportedOperation` and how can I test for it?

More generally, how should I go about finding out what something like this is. I can't see anywhere in the source code where it's raised, so I'm guessing it's a wrapper around a lower level error - but how should I deal with those?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`UnsupportedOperation` is [ghc-specific](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.6.2/html/libraries/base-4.6.0.1/src/GHC-IO-Exception.html#IOErrorType). So you have to import `GHC.IO.Exception`, it contains everything you need to check exception type.

Here is an example:

```
import Control.Exception
import GHC.IO.Exception

main :: IO ()
main = do
  action `catch` (\(IOError _ UnsupportedOperation _ _ _ _) -> print "UnsupportedOperation")
  where
  action = throw $ IOError Nothing UnsupportedOperation "loc" "desc" Nothing Nothing
```

Comment: Would you mind giving an example? I'm trying `IOError _ UnsupportedOperation _ _ _ _ -> Just x` but getting complaints about not exportion IOError/IOException.

Comment: I'm not sure what is exactly wrong with your pattern matching, it looks ok for me. I added full example that compiles and works for me.

Comment: Hah! Doing an unqualified import completely failed to occur to me! Thanks!

Comment: The error was in the import statement - I couldn't work out how to import the correct constructors, seemingly.

Comment: Can anyone tell me how to find out whether certain things are GHC-specific?

Comment: @phunehehe http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/6.12.2/html/libraries/base-4.2.0.1/src/GHC-IO-Exception.html If you look three quarters of the way down the page under IOErrorType, it lists both Haskell and GHC specific errors.